# I am having issues with my code executing a the boolean operation correctly and limiting the value of a variable as define in the operation

Tags: python

Here is my code-

```
board=['','']

from IPython.display import clear_output
def display_board(board):
    print(board[7]+'|'+board[8]+'|'+board[9])
    print(board[4]+'|'+board[5]+'|'+board[6])
    print(board[1]+'|'+board[2]+'|'+board[3])

test_board=['']*10
display_board(test_board)
```

def player_input():

```
marker=''

# keep asking ot select X or O t oplayer one

while not(marker=='X'or marker== 'O'):
    
    marker= input('Player one, select either X or O :').upper()
    if marker =='X':
        return ('X', 'O')
    else:
        marker=='O'
        return('O','X')
    
player_input()

test_board=['','','','','','','','','','']

def place_marker(board,marker,position):
    


     board[position]= marker
place_marker(test_board,'$',8)
display_board(test_board)

def win_check(board, mark):
    # checking who wins tic tac to base on the input X or O or marker
    # check all columns, to make sure the marker is the same
    # check diagonals.
    return ((board[7]==board[8]==board[9]==mark) or
    (board[4]==mark and board[5]==mark and board [6]==mark) or
    (board[1]==board[2]==board[3]==mark) or
    (board[7]==mark and board[5]==mark and board [3]==mark) or
    (board[1]==mark and board[5]==mark and board [9]==mark) or
    (board[7]==board[4]==board[1]==mark) or
    (board[8]==board[5]==board[2]==mark) or
    (board[9]==board[6]==board[3]==mark))

    display_board(test_board)
    win_check(test_board,'X')
 #random module
import random

def choose_first():
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        return 'player1'
    else:
        return 'player2'


choose_first()

def space_check(test_board,position):
    
    return test_board[position]==' '

    #Here is where I encounter the problem, based on what I have before, all the spaces are empty. Therefore, I write in my program the following condition, if all spaces are full from 1 to 9 return "true" other wise return "False", I should get a "false" since there are not values in test_board but regardless on how I am writting it I always get a true.  I am not sire what I am missing?
def full_board_check(test_board):
for i in range(1,10):
    if space_check==''in test_board:
        return False
    else:
        return True


full_board_check(test_board)
```

$Second problem here I am using a "in range" of 1 to 10, this is to represent the spaces I have available for the users to enter their option (in Test_board) but I can put in 10 or 11> and it will take it. How can I limit this to the 9 spaces I have available?

def player_choice (test_board):
position=0
while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(test_board,position):
position= int(input('Select a position (1-9) ' ))

return position

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't look right: `if space_check==''in test_board:`, and I think the whole function is wrong, as you're returning True before checking all the values.  Also `space_check` is actually looking for a space, but you initialize the board with empty strings, not spaces.  Try this:

```
def space_check(test_board,position):
    return test_board[position]==''

def full_board_check(test_board):
    """Returns True if all spaces are filled"""
    for i in range(1,10):
        if space_check(test_board, i):
            return False    # We found an empty slot
    return True    # All slots are filled
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I originally had a similar format, however I could not get it to work, maybe I had a n extra spacing somewhere

Comment: However in the second part of the problem,  I cannot seem to limit the range of the spaces that are available on the board, there should be only 9 but when i preformed a check I am availbe to enter more than that, any suggestion about that one

Comment: def player_choice (test_board):
    position=0
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(test_board,position):
        position= int(input('Select a position (1-9) ' ))
        
    return position

Comment: Make sure the "return position" statement is not in the loop.  Make sure "return" lines up with "while" indent-wise.